# EAAccessoryDidConnectNotification doesn't fire

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, eaaccessory

I'm trying to learn about CoreBluetooth and External Accessories on iOS.

First, I tried to see a list of devices connect to my phone via Bluetooth via `print(EAAccessoryManager.sharedAccessoryManager().connectedAccessories)` ... despite having 3 devices connected (according to the Settings app), I'm given an empty array.

Next, I tried registering for connect / disconnect notifications:

```
import UIKit
import ExternalAccessory

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self,
            selector: "somethingConnected:",
            name: EAAccessoryDidConnectNotification,
            object: nil)

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self,
            selector: "somethingDisconnected:",
            name: EAAccessoryDidDisconnectNotification,
            object: nil)

        EAAccessoryManager.sharedAccessoryManager().registerForLocalNotifications()
    }

    func somethingConnected(name: EAAccessory) {
        print("here")
    }

    func somethingDisconnected(name: EAAccessory) {
        print("there")
    }
}
```

... I receive nothing when I turn off/on (and thus disconnect/connect) a simple Bluetooth speaker I have.

[I *am* seeing this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23349974/eaaccessorydidconnectnotification-not-firing-until-bluetooth-accessory-picker-co) (notifications not delivering until after the completion block of `showBluetoothAccessoryPickerWithNameFilter()` executes), but, generally, it seems like either:

A) Something with iOS isn't working correctly

B) I'm doing something wrong (the more likely of the two).

Do I need to have a special MFI certificate installed to see a list of connected Accessories?  Why aren't notifications delivering?

Any recommendations / code examples are greatly appreciated.

**Update**

Most importantly:  Still don't know why `connectedAccessories` doesn't work, so advice on this piece is greatly desired.

That said, re-reading the Apple Developer documentation, I don't believe that it's correct / possible to use  `NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver` with these types of notifications.

Specifically, the documentation states that EA notifications will not be delivered until `showBluetoothAccessoryPickerWithNameFilter()` is called -- e.g. the `EAAccessoryDidConnectNotification` and `EAAccessoryDidDisconnectNotification` are meant to inform the app about what the User did with the picker dialogue.  It doesn't seem that they are system-level notifications that can be picked up by `NSNotificationCenter`.

Please correct me if this is an incorrect reading.

Comment: This is not answer. I am facing same problem, did you find a solution @DanShev ?

Answer (score 2):

you should change

```
selector: "somethingConnected:"
```

into

```
selector: @selector(somethingConnected:)
```

,than it will fire.
For more details, please see the following website:
[Why does EAAccessoryDidConnectNotification occur twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6874853/why-does-eaaccessorydidconnectnotification-occur-twice)

Comment: it seems your code is Swift, oops. I made a mistake, sorry for that. But the provided link may solve your problem.